# Extrair texto entre tags HTML com Indy IdHTTP com Delphi

Tags: delphi

Tenho um site html que contém:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Teste 1</h1>
<h2>Teste 2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou extraindo o conteúdo do site e jogando no MEMO com:

```
IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; IndyLibrary)';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
HTML := IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.site.com/link.html');
Memo1.Text := (HTML);
```

O problema que não consigo retirar o conteúdo entre as tags `<h1> .. </h1>` ou seja, Teste 1 e jogar num label.

Comment: Como você está fazendo para tentar extrair?

Answer (score 5):

Tem essa *function* aqui que eu uso pra fazer isso de arquivos **HTML** e/ou **XML** :)

```pascal
function ExtractText(aText, OpenTag, CloseTag : String) : String;
{ Retorna o texto dentro de 2 tags (open & close Tag's) }
var
  iAux, kAux : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  if (Pos(CloseTag, aText) <> 0) and (Pos(OpenTag, aText) <> 0) then
  begin
    iAux := Pos(OpenTag, aText) + Length(OpenTag);
    kAux := Pos(CloseTag, aText);
    Result := Copy(aText, iAux, kAux-iAux);
  end;
end;
```

Parâmetros:

- *aText*: seria conteúdo do XML ou HTML;
- *OpenTag*: seria a tag que abre (no seu caso, por exemplo `<h1>`);
- *CloseTag*: seria a tag que fecha (no seu caso, por exemplo `</h1>`);

Aí pra você fazer a chamada dessa function faria, por exemplo:

```
variavelString = ExtractText(Memo1.Text,'<h1>','</h1>');
```

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço!

Answer (score -2):

Primeiro eu substituo a tag `<p> e </p>` pela quebra de linha do Delphi, depois e percorro o texto procurando pela entrada < e saída > do HTML;
Por fim retiro os caracteres especiais do HTML.

```
function TFuncoes.RetiraTagsHTML(ConteudoHTML: string): string;
var
  TagInicio, TagFim, TagLength: integer;
begin
  //substituo primeiro os parágrafos para saltar a linha
  ConteudoHTML := StringReplace(StringReplace(ConteudoHTML//
    , '</p>', '</p>' + #10#13, [rfReplaceAll])      //
    , ' /p>', ' /p>' + #10#13, [rfReplaceAll]);

  TagInicio := Pos('<', ConteudoHTML); // posição de busca de primeira <

  while (TagInicio > 0) do
  begin  // enquanto há uma < em S
    TagFim := Pos('>', ConteudoHTML);       // encontra a correspondente >
    TagLength := TagFim - TagInicio + 1;
    Delete(ConteudoHTML, TagInicio, TagLength); // exclui a tag
    TagInicio := Pos('<', ConteudoHTML);       // pesquisa a proxima <
  end;

  //Por último substituo os caractéres especiais do HTML
  ConteudoHTML := StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(//
    ConteudoHTML //
    , '&aacute;', 'á', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&eacute;', 'é', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&iacute;', 'í', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&oacute;', 'ó', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&uacute;', 'ú', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&acirc;', 'â', [rfReplaceAll])  //
    , '&ecirc;', 'ê', [rfReplaceAll])  //
    , '&ocirc;', 'ô', [rfReplaceAll])  //
    , '&agrave;', 'à', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&uuml;', 'ü', [rfReplaceAll])   //
    , '&ccedil;', 'ç', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&atilde;', 'ã', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&otilde;', 'õ', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&ntilde;', 'ñ', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Aacute;', 'Á', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Eacute;', 'É', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Iacute;', 'Í', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Oacute;', 'Ó', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Uacute;', 'Ú', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Acirc;', 'Â', [rfReplaceAll])  //
    , '&Ecirc;', 'Ê', [rfReplaceAll])  //
    , '&Ocirc;', 'Ô', [rfReplaceAll])  //
    , '&Agrave;', 'À', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Ccedil;', 'Ç', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Atilde;', 'Ã', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Otilde;', 'Õ', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&Ntilde;', 'Ñ', [rfReplaceAll]) //
    , '&amp;', '&', [rfReplaceAll])    //
    , '&quot;', '"', [rfReplaceAll])   //
    , '&lt;', '<', [rfReplaceAll])     //
    , '&gt;', '>', [rfReplaceAll])     //
    , '&nbsp;', ' ', [rfReplaceAll]    //
  );

  Result := ConteudoHTML; // retorna o resultado
end;
```

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, Tudo Bem!! cara. Parabéns pela resposta, mas tendo em vista que muitas outras pessoas podem vir a ler ela no futuro, poderia descrever sua solução e código? ajuda bastante gente, é uma das dicas que a comunidade tenta passar para todos. respostas bem elaboradas.